# "Where should I pay the tickets?" Does this sentence make sense?

Tags: word-usage, prepositions, direct-objects

- Where should I pay the tickets?

This is from an English material for students. ([Sightseeing 3: Buying a ticket](https://eikaiwa.weblio.jp/information/travel-english/travel-english-buy-a-ticket-1))

I learnt at school that you "pay money" and you "pay **for** tickets".  Is "pay tickets" also OK?

Comment: You can also *pay a fine/fee/tax/price/debt*, but in general, yes, you pay (money) **for** an item.

Comment: It appears to say "Where should I pay for the tickets?" However, there is a mistake; we say "I **would** like to buy tickets", not "I like to".

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: you are correct and that travel English guide is wrong.

The verb *pay* can either be transitive (takes direct object) or intransitive (takes either a indirect object, or no object).

Often, we use the transitive version, *A paid B*, to mean that A gave money to B for some goods or service.

Ex:

*I paid Alice $20.*

We use the intransitive version, *A paid for B* to mean A gave money to someone who is not named for some goods or service B.

Ex:

*I paid for the tickets*

**BUT**, there's another use that falls somewhere between these two general rules:

*I paid the bill*

In this case, we're using the transitive version, but it does not mean *I gave money to the bill*, it means *I gave money to someone else in the amount that the bill indicated*.

There are a handful of nouns that can be used here, similarly to *bill*.  Some examples are:

*I paid the amount*

*I paid the debt*

*I paid the wages*

*I paid five dollars*

And most confusing of all (in this context): *I paid the ticket*!

The trick there is that *ticket* can either mean:

> a certificate or token showing that a fare or admission fee has been paid

OR

> a summons or warning issued to a traffic-law violator

[Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/ticket)

When a traffic cop gives you a speeding ticket, you *pay the ticket*.  But you cannot *pay the ticket for the museum*.

Answer (score 1):

No, you're right. *pay the tickets* is simply a mistake.

Answer (score -1):

The correct thing to say is "where should I buy the tickets?"

In "buy" the object is what you will get. "Pay" is about what you give for it. An example using each: "I paid $35 to buy drinks for everyone". "Buy" can also mean the whole transaction, for example "I bought this cat for $100". There's no need to say "pay" since buying includes paying.

"Pay for" is special. It means "finish buying by giving the money". You'd say it after you've starting buying something. At a restaurant you might get the food then say "find a table while I pay for it". If you ordered the food over the phone, you might say "I'll go in and pay for it". But no one would ever say "I'm hungry -- let's go over there and pay for a sandwich" (they'd say "buy").